# JQuery Modal close minimizes window for a few users (in IE9)

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-9, jquery-ui-dialog

So, a few users are experiencing their browser window minimizing when they click save on this modal window. For those users, it's consistent, but it's just a small number of users. Most people are using IE9, and everyone that has this problem is using IE9. It happens on the `.dialog('close');` call, and it minimizes before it reaches the close function. Does anyone have any ideas?

```
$("#new-specified").dialog($.extend({}, ns.modalOptions, {
            open: function () {
                if (ns.disabled) {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
                $(this).dialog("option", "title", app.viewModels.MissionViewModel.EditingSpecified() ? "EDIT SPECIFIED TASK" : "NEW SPECIFIED TASK");
                $(this).parent().find("button:contains('Cancel')").removeClass().addClass("cancel-button");
                $(this).parent().find("button:contains('SAVE')").removeClass().addClass("save-button");
                app.viewModels.MissionViewModel.CurrentSpecified().TempDescription(app.functions.htmlUnescape(app.viewModels.MissionViewModel.CurrentSpecified().Description()));
                if (app.viewModels.MissionViewModel.SpecifiedTasks().length === 0) {
                    app.viewModels.MissionViewModel.CurrentSpecified().IsMainEffort(true);
                }
            },
            buttons: {
                "Cancel": function() {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                },
                "SAVE": function () {
                    var newSpecified = app.viewModels.MissionViewModel.CurrentSpecified();
                    newSpecified.Description(app.functions.htmlEscape(newSpecified.TempDescription()));
                    newSpecified.Validate();
                    if (newSpecified.IsInError()) {
                        return;
                    }
                    if (!app.viewModels.MissionViewModel.EditingSpecified()) {
                        app.viewModels.MissionViewModel.SpecifiedTasks.push(newSpecified);
                    } else {
                        app.viewModels.MissionViewModel.OldSpecified().CopyFrom(newSpecified);
                        newSpecified = app.viewModels.MissionViewModel.OldSpecified();
                    }

                    app.viewModels.MissionViewModel.CurrentSpecified(new app.models.SpecifiedTaskViewModel());
                    var isMainEffort = newSpecified.IsMainEffort();
                    var index = isMainEffort ? app.viewModels.MissionViewModel.SpecifiedTasks().indexOf(newSpecified) : -1;
                    app.viewModels.MissionViewModel.VerifyMainEffort(index);
                    ns.setupSpecifiedModal();
                    //VV This line below minimizes
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                    ns.setupDroppable();
                }
            },
            close: function() {
                // We don't reach here before the window minimizes
                app.viewModels.MissionViewModel.CurrentSpecified(new app.models.SpecifiedTaskViewModel());
                app.viewModels.MissionViewModel.EditingSpecified(false);

                app.viewModels.MissionViewModel.VerifyMainEffort(-1);
                ns.saveMissionToServer();
            }
        }));
```

Comment: As far as I know, there is no way to minimize the window from JavaScript, so that's really weird.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought, too. It only happens for a few people, but it's consistently the same spot for those people...

Comment: Maybe it's some browser plugin on those machines?

Answer (score 0):

This question might have the solution: [Dynamically loading jQuery mobile causes IE to minimize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7163648/dynamically-loading-jquery-mobile-causes-ie-to-minimize)

Seems like calling `blur()` forces the IE window to the back of the stack. If you're using jQuery Mobile, here is the related issue: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/2057

If you're not using jQuery Mobile, look for calls to `blur()` in your code.

Comment: This seems like it could be related. I'm not using jQuery Mobile, but I do have an iframe. It's only two specific versions of IE9 it happens in, so right now we're just telling those people to upgrade their browser to the latest version of IE9, and that's fixing it.

Answer (score 0):

This was also found in jquery-UI 1.10.0: http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/9420.

As first comment suggest, the cause is that `blur()` is called on document.body.

As a workaround you can override `body.blur()`, look at [How do I disable body.blur() in IE8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12466693/how-do-i-disable-body-blur-in-ie8)